# Why Java public API has private method?

Tags: java-me

I was looking at java.security.BasicPermission API the other day. Why does it have a private method?

private  void   readObject(ObjectInputStream s)
          readObject is called to restore the state of the BasicPermission from a stream.

Sorry, I wasn't clear about what I asked. The class is just an example. There are many of them in Java library. All of them are read|write Object method. When they designed this API, why would they add a private method that an application can't use?

Comment: Please clarify your question - as you can see from the answers, it's not clear whether you're familiar with the idea of private methods in general but don't understand why *this particular one* exists, or whether you don't understand the purpose of private methods in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

`readObject` is a used by the Java serialization framework when deserializing, to provide support for custom operations. Unlike most private methods, it usually *wouldn't* be called within the class itself - instead it's called by the framework / JVM, which obviously violates normal expectations somewhat.

See the [docs for `Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) for more details.

Comment: I think his question is more about private / public accessors than the actual class itself.

Comment: @Arindam: What makes you think that? He's given a very specific example which doesn't fall into the normal situation of "private methods are called within the implementation" - I think it's a pretty large coincidence if he just *happened* to pick that unusual situation without it being of any significance.

Answer (score 1):

That method is probably called internally by one of the other public methods and should not be the concern of the API user.

Comment: I doubt that it's called by the public methods in this case - it's a bit of a special case for serialization.

Comment: I went over the BasicPermission.java. Both of the private methods are not used inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

A private method is a method that cannot be accessed by the API, but is used internally to do something.

For example, take a real world example like a Microwave. It would have external user inputs like bake(), heat(), etc ... but a private internal function like cookFor(Time minutes, Temperature t).

So now the Microwave implementation is really simple,

```
public void bake() {
  cookFor(45, 300);
}

public void heat() {
  cookFor(5, 100);
}
```

etc. The reason we have functions is to write good procedural programs, and the private/public descriptor is used to encapsulate the class.